# Calculate the avg for consecutive 30 days data

Tags: sql, ms-access, days

I am looking for a query that will give the data for last 30 days and last to last 30days.

e.g - if today is 6/30 den i should be able to pull data till 5/30 and 4/30. I have tried the below code but it gives only the data for last 30 days

```
SELECT Avg(Sub.Ticket) AS Average2
FROM (SELECT Fulldate, COUNT(Ticket_Number) AS Ticket
      FROM RawData
      GROUP BY Fulldate
     )  AS sub
WHERE ((([RawData].[FullDate])>=#6/30/2016#-30-30));
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what are you trying to calculate exactly. Is that the AVG for the last 30 days and another AVG for the last 30+30 (=60) days?

Comment: Avg for last 30 days and another avg for 30 days before that

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. See the answer below.

Comment: `GROUP BY datediff("d", [RawData].[FullDate], #6/30/2016#) \ 30` This is integer division.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the results in 1 row, 2 columns:

```
SELECT 
  AVG(sub.TicketLast30) AS AverageLast30,
  AVG(sub.TicketPrev30) AS AveragePrev30
FROM (
  SELECT Fulldate, 
    COUNT(IIF(Fulldate BETWEEN (DATE()-30) AND DATE(), Ticket_Number, 0) AS TicketLast30,
    COUNT(IIF(Fulldate BETWEEN (DATE()-60) AND (DATE()-30), Ticket_Number, 0) AS TicketPrev30
  FROM RawData
  WHERE Fulldate BETWEEN (DATE()-60) AND DATE()
  GROUP BY Fulldate
) AS sub
```

If you want the results in 2 rows with 1 column:

```
SELECT 
  AVG(sub.Ticket) AS Average30
FROM (
  SELECT Fulldate, 
    COUNT(Ticket_Number) AS Ticket
  FROM RawData
  WHERE Fulldate BETWEEN (DATE()-60) AND (DATE()-30)
  GROUP BY Fulldate
) AS sub
UNION ALL
SELECT 
  AVG(sub.Ticket) AS Average30
FROM (
  SELECT Fulldate, 
    COUNT(Ticket_Number) AS Ticket
  FROM RawData
  WHERE Fulldate BETWEEN (DATE()-30) AND DATE()
  GROUP BY Fulldate
 ) AS sub
```

Comment: (cc: @Biplab1985 ) These queries are written in T-SQL (for Microsoft SQL Server), not Access SQL.

Comment: Thought so, any suggestion for access

Comment: Let me rephrase - say i need to find the average of Tickets by dates of last month. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Edited the queries to use Access syntax, so insted of GETDATE() you have DATE(). The GROUP BY and the AVG aggregation should work in Access too.

Comment: `BEETWEEN` needs fixin'